# Google OAuth using embedded web view

Tags: android, ios, google-api, google-oauth

My mobile app on both Android and iOS uses Cordova’s InAppBrowser plugin to allow users’ to authenticate using Google OAuth2. As I understand, Google will be removing that capability in a few months in order to support making it easier for users to sign in using existing session from the system browser.

The issue we have is that our app's sign in process actually needs to *not* use any existing session credentials. Our app is an employee time clock that may be used on a shared mobile device (e.g., kiosk). Normally employees clock IN and OUT of work using an employee pin, but an administrator may sign into a special administrator mode to do things like set up a new time clock or access privileged functions. We rely on the administrator having to enter fresh credentials each time. We don’t want any existing session to remain around as the device is not considered safe for that. I hope that make sense.

It looks like Google's sign-in SDK for both Android and iOS have a way to disconnect users, which I assume means the session will be locally removed. However, Google sign-in is not central enough to our business that we want to have to integrate and take on the burden of maintaining two native SDK's for it.

​Is there any way that Google can whitelist our OAuth key​ to continue to use the existing in-app auth as our use-case does not fit into Google’s primary objective for this change?

Comment: I really don't think that Stack can tell you if google would white list your app.  There for this question is opinion based and my opinion is that.  I really don't think google will white list anyone's app.

Comment: Google is saying to post any questions about their oauth migration to stack overflow, as mentioned in this blog post:
https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html

Comment: "If you have any questions with the migration, please post to Stack Overflow tagged with “google-oauth”."   Doesn't say anything about Google specify responding.  Only google can answer your question.  If you want an answer directly from google you have to contact google.   Stack is a community sight which can not grantee that google checks the tags.